# cakephp4 routing to a unknown path

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp4 when i access my website

```
  http://crm.xx.com/users/login
```

and type
https://crm.xx.com

I get redirected to this

```
 https://crm.xx/crm_system/users/login?redirect=%2F
```

There is no where in the routes code that its doing this(routes.php pr in appController), so i dont understand how to fix this problem or where to look. The subdomain i  setup as crm.step-familydynamics.com and points to the correct folder for the crm.. Where am i looking to find out where this is redirecting like it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your home page controller. Thus, the home page will be visible to everyone who accesses it. Use with pages that do not require authentication!

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow('home'); //Add the routes you want
    }
```